# Link unconnected components after deleting bridge node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j to represent a network.

In my use case, when I delete a node that bridges two or more graph components, I would like to add an edge to ensure the components are still connected.

For example, if I have the graph below:

```
A - B - D
    |
    C
```

The node `B` is a bridge for `A`, `C`, and `D` and if I delete it, these components will become disconnected. So upon deletion of `B`, I would like the result to be something like:

```
A - D     or     A - D
    |            |
    C            C
```

Or any other combination that ensures the remaining components are still connected somehow.

I'm struggling to write a Cypher query to achieve this specification and haven't been able to find a solution online. Wondering if I could find some help here!

Note: in my system, the edges are treated as undirected (which is why I didn't use arrows in the diagram above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can optionally match the connected nodes and connect those nodes after deleting node **b**.

The following query does not produce the exact result you need but it keeps the nodes connected.

```
MATCH (b:node{name: 'b'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (n1)--(b)--(n2)
DETACH DELETE b
WITH n1, n2 WHERE n2 IS NOT NULL AND n1 IS NOT NULL 
MERGE (n1)-[:CONNECTED]-(n2)
```

**Explanation:**

Line 1 -> Find the `b` node

Line 2 -> Find the related nodes(n1 & n2)

Line 3 -> Delete the node

Line 4 -> Check n1 & n2 are not null otherwise cypher will throw error

Line 5 -> Add relationship using MERGE, It will create relationship only if the nodes are not connected already.

1. **OPTIONAL MATCH** is required otherwise it will not delete the **b** nodes that are not connected to any nodes.
2. **NULL check**(n2 IS NOT NULL AND n1 IS NOT NULL) is required to avoid errors when n1 or n2 is NULL.

[image: Graph Structure after deleting b with above query]

Comment: Although I don't quite understand the query, it works like a charm! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, do you mind explaining what you mean by "it does not produce the exact result you need"? From what I tested so far, it does exactly what I need.

Comment: You need either A-D-C or D-A-C but it creates both, I added the screenshot after deletion of B

Comment: Oh, that's not a problem for me. Your solution works perfectly for me.